# AttributeError when calling .append() on a set to add a list

Tags: python, list, set, append

I keep getting an `AttributeError` on line 6 of my code:

```
date_set.append(date).
```

Don't understand why. Could someone explain my error?

```
dates = [[5, 7], [7, 9], [9,10],[8, 9]]
def answer(dates):
    date_set = set()
    for date in dates:
        if date[0] <= date[1]:    
            date_set.append(date)
    date_total = [date for date in date_set]
    return len(date_total)
```

Comment: `set` objects use `add()`, not `append()`. Next time, please at least try looking in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_set.append(date)
```

`set()` hasn't append() method

You should use `set.update()` method or `set.add()`

Answer (score 0):

You get an attribute error because there is no such attribute.  The word `append` means to add to the end, but sets are unordered.  To add something to a set, use `.add()`:

```
for date in dates:
    if date[0] <= date[1]:
        date_set.add(date)
```

The easier way to do it, though, would be to use a set comprehension:

```
date_set = {date for date in dates if date[0] <= date[1]}
```

You don't even need to create a set, though.  Just do this:

```
def answer(dates):
    return sum(1 for date in dates if date[0] <= date[1])
```

Comment: Hmmm. Tried this and my code still appears to not be working. Are there any other problems you can see with it? Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, to make a list from a set you could use `list(date_set)`, but you don't need to convert to a list anyway.  Sets have lengths just like lists.  There are other things that could be improved, but I don't see anything that would make your code not work.

Comment: For your last suggestion w/out using a set, what answer should that generate for a list like `dates = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 5]]` Very new to python, sorry if this stuff is obvious

Comment: Sorry I took so long.  I just tested it and it came out with `5`.